# Jquery fullcalendar with eventDrop not working in production

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using fullcalendar in my app and also Jquery drag and drop to drag events into the calendar.
It all works fine in development environment but not working when publishing in IIS..
I already checked that the script paths are correct.
it seems like all is working except the eventDrop and eventReceive in my fullcalendar object.

here is my fullcalendar code:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: $(window).height() * 0.90,
    scrollTime: "08:00:00", // Starting hours scroll starts in the view
    timezone: 'local',
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    eventLimit: true, // limit events in a cell for all non-agenda views
    aspectRatio: 2.50, // control the day cell height in month view
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
    allDaySlot: false, // remove "all days" cell
    titleRangeSeparator: " - ",
    header: {
        left: 'next,prev today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaDay,agendaFiveDay,week1,month1'
    },
    slotLabelFormat: 'H:mm',
    defaultView: "agendaFiveDay",
    editable: true,
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
    // triggered when a drop activity from an external source occurs
    eventReceive: function (event) {
        addActivity(event.start, event.resourceId, event.docNum, event.docType, event.title, event.tooltipContent, shifted, g_psDb, g_sUser, function (addActivityResult) {
            if (addActivityResult.Message != "OK") {
                toastr["error"](addActivityResult.Message)
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id)
            }
            else {
                // set the activity id of the new added activity recieved from the DB 
                event.id = addActivityResult.ActivityId;
                // remove the dropped item from the open tasks list in the view
                elements = $('#openActivities .item')
                $.each(elements, function (i) {
                    if ($(this).data('event').docNum == event.docNum) {
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    },
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
        element.css("background-color", event.color);

        // create the tooltip for each event
        s = moment(event.start).format("HH:mm");
        e = moment(event.end).format("HH:mm");
        element.qtip({
            content: {
                text: event.tooltipContent,
                title: e + ' - ' + s
            },
            style: 'qtip-bootstrap', // Give it some style
            position: {
                my: 'left center',
                at: 'right middle'
            },
            show: {
                delay: 500, solo: true
            },
            hide: {
                when: 'mouseout', delay: 400
            }
        })
        // Create context menu when right clicking an activity, ignore when it is background activity
        element.bind('mousedown', function (e) {
            if ((e.which == 3) && (this.className != "fc-bgevent")) {
                $('#menu').hide();
                $('#menu').css({ 'top': e.pageY - 50, 'left': e.pageX, 'position': 'absolute', 'border': '1px solid black' });
                $('#menu').data("element", element) // pass the DOM element to the menu
                $('#menu').data("event", event) // pass the activity OBJECT to the menu
                $('#menu').show();
            }
        });
    },
    eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
        // give background color to even days
        if (view.name == 'week1' || view.name == "agendaFiveDay" || view.name == "agendaFourDay" || view.name == "agendaTwoDay") {
            $.each($("td"), function () {
                var date = $(this).attr("data-date");
                if (typeof date != "undefined" && date != false) {
                    // If element has thiViewss attribute
                    date = new Date(date);
                    var day = date.getDate().toString();
                    if (day % 2 == 0)
                        $(this).css("background-color", "#f6f6f6");
                }
            })
        }
    },
    views: {
        month1: {
            type: 'month',
            duration: { months: 1 },
            // group by day FIRST with resources underneath
            groupByDateAndResource: true
        },
        week1: {
            titleFormat: 'YYYY, D MMMM',   // The date format for this view
            type: 'agenda',
            duration: { weeks: 1 },
            /// group by day FIRST with resources underneath
            groupByDateAndResource: true,
            columnFormat: "ddd D/M"
        },
        agendaFourDay: {
            titleFormat: 'YYYY, D MMMM',   // The date format for this view
            type: 'agenda',
            duration: { days: 4 },
            groupByDateAndResource: true,
            columnFormat: "ddd D/M"
        },
        agendaFiveDay: {
            titleFormat: 'YYYY, D MMMM',   // The date format for this view
            type: 'agenda',
            duration: { weeks: 1 },
            groupByDateAndResource: true,
            columnFormat: "ddd D/M",
            hiddenDays: [5, 6] // don't show Friday and Sautarday
        },
        agendaTwoDay: {
            titleFormat: 'YYYY, D MMMM',   // The date format for this view
            type: 'agenda',
            duration: { days: 2 },
            groupByDateAndResource: true
        }
    },
    resources: [], // This line must be here to implemet resources in the calendar
    eventSources: [
        {
            events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                var startDate = new Date(start);
                var endDate = new Date(end);
                getFixedActivities(startDate, endDate, function (events) {
                    callback(events)
                })
            }
        },
        {
            events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                var startDate = new Date(start);
                var endDate = new Date(end);
                getAvailableHours(startDate, endDate, function (events) {
                    callback(events)
                })
            },
            color: 'green' // TODO: set as database variable
        }
    ],
    // trigers each time an activity resizes
    eventResize: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {
        updateActivity(event, shifted, function (activityResult) {
            if (activityResult.Message != "OK") {
                // alert(activityResult.Message)
                toastr["error"](activityResult.Message)
                revertFunc();
            }
        })
    },
    // triggers every time an internal activity being moved
    eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {
        updateActivity(event, shifted, function (activityResult) {
            if (activityResult.Message != "OK") {
                //alert(activityResult.Message)
                toastr["error"](activityResult.Message)
                revertFunc();
            }
        })
    }
});
    function OnSuccess(response) {
    $("#openActivities").empty();
    var activities = response.d;
    $(activities).each(function (i) {
        // format the date
        var dueDate = new Date(parseInt(this.DueDate.substr(6)));
        dueDate = dueDate.toLocaleDateString();
        // Create list item with the data retrieved
        var $element = $("<li class='item'>" + this.WebListItem + "</li>");
        // add the created item to the list
        $("#openActivities").append($element);
        // animation of adding items to open activities list
        $element.delay(200 * i).animate({ opacity: 1 }).slideDown('slow');
        // store data on the list item so the calendar will be able get it later
        $element.data('event', {
            title: this.Content, // Use the title input as the event title
            duration: "01:00", // The duration in HH:mm format
            docType: this.DocType,
            docNum: this.DocNum,
            color: g_defaultStatusColor,
            tooltipContent: this.TooltipContent,
            cancel: false // will determine if to remove the event from the calendar 
        });

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $element.draggable({
            containment: 'window',
            scroll: false,
            helper: 'clone',
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0,  //  original position after the drag
            start: function () {
                $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
                $(this).css("opacity", 0.4);
            },
            stop: function () {
                $(this).css("opacity", 1);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Please define "not working". Have you debugged the page to see where the process fails? Do you get any console errors? Did you deploy jQueryUI correctly to your production environment?

Comment: No errors in cosole. The drop Event is never triggered (but on dev env it does). What do you mean by deploying jqueryUI correctly?

Comment: I mean, is it in the correct location on the server and loaded into the page successfully (check the network tab to see if loading that file is successful (200 OK response)? Dropping external events wouldn't work if loading that file failed.

Comment: Slightly amended /simplfied example but which demonstrates the code itself is alright, assuming everything loads correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/toytd26b/2/ . In the absence of further info, I guess you need to start playing spot the difference between your dev and production environments.

Comment: Yes, it is loaded correctly, I can see it in the sources tab

Comment: Well, I cannot reproduce your problem at all, sorry. There's nothing in the code above which appears to cause it. Something is clearly different about the operating environment, but we can't see anything about that, and you don't seem to be experiencing any actual errors which would give people a clue, so unless anyone else finds this question and has a better idea then you'll have to hunt it yourself I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, I know that the info I supplied isn't much, and I do not get any errors in console... I hope this is related to some IIS configuration so I will be able to track this one down... thanks anyway.